# How to convert text to binary UTF-16 String in java?

Tags: java, encoding, utf-16

I am doing a project which requires me to convert arabic  text to binary string UTF-16 instead of utf-8. I converted the text to UTF-8 Binarystring but have no idea how to change the process to utf-16 insted of utf-8..? because when i changed it to utf-16 it takes  4bytes  for every codepoints instead of 2 bytes .I know Arabic characters range between(range 0600  to FFFF hex) takes exactly 2 bytes for every codepoint in utf-16.So I do not know what is the problem in my code .

// Convert the text to binary

```
public static String getBinaryFromText(String secretText) {
    byte[] bytes = secretText.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    StringBuilder binary = new StringBuilder();
    for (byte b : bytes) {
        int val = b;
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            binary.append((val & 128) == 0 ? 0 : 1);
            val <<= 1;
        }
    }

    return binary.toString();
}
```

Comment: Try `byte[] bytes = secretText.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE);`

Comment: Thank you, by (UTF-16LE), takes  2 bytes for every codepoint .

Comment: what is the difference between(utf-16) and (utf-16LE)..?

Comment: [Byte order encoding schemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Byte_order_encoding_schemes).

Answer (score 1):

Strings are intrinsically UTF-16. Each char is a UTF-16 codepoint. `secretText.charAt(0)` is the first UTF-16 character, etc, etc.

You can use a `Charset` to do the conversion treating the UTF-16 as a byte sequence. Do `Charset.forName("UTF-16")` and use the `encode` method.